# C program that multiplies numbers from 1 to N

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that multiplies all the numbers from `1` to `N` where `N` is a number that was entered by the user.

**For example if I type in `5`, I want to the program to multiply every number from `1` to `5`.**

The program would calculate `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120`.

I am new to C and programming in general but I managed to write this code that does something similar to what I want.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int N, rem, prod = 1;

    printf("Enter the value of N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    while(N != 0)
    {
        rem = N % 10;
        prod *= rem;
        N /=  10;
    }

    printf("%d", prod);

    return 0;
}
```

My code multiples each number with each other but the user has to enter each one manually.

For example if I wanted to achieve the output I mentioned before, I would have to type in `12345`.

**Instead I would like to type just `5`.**

I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: Why is your code computing a reminder (`rem`)?

Comment: What is the largest `N` that may be entered?

Comment: This is called "factorial", and there are zillions of questions about it.

Comment: I did not think about the largest number for N that can entered. However, for my purposes it is ok that I use ``int`` for N since I will not be needing this for numbers that large.

Comment: I did not know what this was called so I had a hard time finding other posts with the problem.

Comment: Where did you get the code for the `while` loop? It seems so *not* fit for this purpose that I wonder if you started by thinking of the problem in a very different way.

Comment: So, you are looking for a [factorial in C](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/factorial), eg: `5! = 1*2*3*4*5`

Comment: I misunderstood what was asked of me so at first I started thinking that if the user could enter each number individually that would be enough. So the user had to enter something like the following: ``1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120`` that is why I have that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need something like:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= N; i++){
    prod *= i;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/H1jPjfYSv)</kbd>

Keep in mind that if `N` is large enough `prod` will eventually overflow.

The max value of an `int` is [usually](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) `2 147 483 647`, 2<sup>31</sup>-1. For this limit value, `12` would be the maximum `N` possible.

You could stretch that to `20` if you use `long long` instead of `int`.

The upper limit of a `long long` is at least `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`, 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

For completion, you should check the return of `scanf` to make sure the input was correctly parsed, *e.g.*:

```
if(scanf("%d", &N) == 1){
    //Ok, input parsed
}
else{
    //input not parsed
}
```

Comment: HINT: Keep in mind that C has no exact sizes for data types. So int MIGHT be 32 bit. But it also could be 16, 64 or whatever bits in size -> Mainly depends on compiler and/or your target platform.

Comment: @hiddenAlpha, mostly correct, that's why used the word "usually". When you say "or whatever bits in size", that's not quite accurate, an `int` must be at least 16 bits.